# I'm in a bit of bind... I have the wrong regalia robe

Tags: graduation

So, I am graduating with my Master's in 3 weeks. The university that I am graduating from is the same one where I did my undergrad. I currently have a bachelor's robe, not a master's one because I figured, the same university, not much difference, and I didn't have the $100+ extra to order another gown. My question is, can I get away with wearing a bachelor's gown for a master's ceremony?

Comment: The bookstore at lots of places provided a rental service. But you need a local answer for your actual question.

Comment: What country? The answer is not going to be the same at Oxford as it is at UC Berkeley.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think most people will care. It will not impact your degree. It will not prevent you from walking across the stage.**

*(answering with a US tilt, from the perspective of someone who attended large public universities in the US midwest; it's possible somewhere else people care about these things more)*

I think your personal comfort is most important here. It's not really anyone else's business, but indeed you'll be in a public place/ceremony. Without knowing your country or institution, I can just say that in a big ceremony at a public US university, no one will care much. As a bit of reassurance from someone who has a bit of social anxiety: *you're just not that important to anyone else*. Everyone there is either graduating, so they are most concerned with their own achievement, or they are supporting someone who is graduating, so they are most concerned with the person they are supporting, not you.

You might stand out a bit, if your robe is highly visibly different from others. It depends entirely on your institution's varieties of robe just how much you will stand out; at some institutions, the master's gear may feature just a small distinction, at other places it may be an entirely different color. Probably, though, you'll all be mostly in black, with some school color highlights someplace.

Some people may look at you and wonder why you're dressed differently. Does that matter to you? If it matters deeply, you might look at other options like renting or try to put out a quick message through social media to see if a past year's graduate might let you purchase or borrow their garb (probably more than a few bought it and have it in their closet and since realized they have no actual use for the thing and would be happy to take your $20 instead).

If someone did happen to question you (they probably won't, but every once in awhile someone is more nosy than they need to be), I think they'd be quickly disarmed by a quip like "Of course I'm wearing my bachelor's gown; I wasn't going to shell out the $100 and I still get to keep my master's degree!" Possibly they'll feel a bit foolish for not thinking of it themselves, but I think you can feel confident in your wise frugality rather than embarrassed by your different appearance.

Comment: In the U.S. and probably elsewhere, the only real difference between masters' and bachelors' robes is the length of the sleeves.  *however,* be sure to find out whether you need a hood.  You probably will, and you can probably rent one.  You might even be able to borrow one from someone who graduated ahead of you.

Answer (score -1):

I would contact your thesis advisor, or the student affairs office, or the inequality office to ask about it. Maybe they will slowly realize how archaic such a ceremony is, or how stressful can be for someone not having the means to be "like the others".

Big thumbs up to you for being brave and stepping out of this nonsense. I am sure there are students getting or using part of their loans to afford the robe.
Even if you could afford it, you would be pushing others that cannot afford it, putting them under pressure of being "like the others" (when the university should teach independent thinking, rather than having degrees as a pass for being accepted in an exclusive club).

I wonder how come that in the modern big push for "inclusivity", wealth inequality is systematically ignored.

Comment: No, I am not really wondering about it, I am sure it is a "mantaining the status-quo" strategy., especially in a strongly money-stratified society like the American one.

Comment: "I wonder how come that in the modern big push for "inclusivity", wealth inequality is systematically ignored." And, by complete coincidence, also discrimination based on educational status.

Comment: While I appreciate the criticisms of some archaic procedures, I don't think it's quite fair to a student who finds themselves in the position of the OP to answer "what should I do about not having the right robe?" with "Be the vanguard of the push against archaic graduation ceremonies and the inequities they cause!" You're taking their minor problem and asking that they escalate it to a major endeavor.

Comment: " I didn't have the $100+ extra to order another gown." 
That's the OP issue, not a minor one. 
I totally understand the puritan/calvinistic way of thinking, if your ancestor is from Ghana you deserve all kind of support (and rightly so), if you do not have 100$ it is your problem (and in the mind of the median wasp person, probably your fault).
I am not asking to escalate. I am just asking OP to add one infinitesimal statistical dot in the student affairs office, in the inequality office, in the interneuronal space of the advisor. Student will without any doubt find a local (L2) solution.